# Why does nestjs framework use a transport layer different than HTTP in a microservices approach?

Tags: node.js, http, microservices, nestjs

I have been developing microservices with Spring Boot for a while, using feign client, rest template and AMPQ brokers to establish communication between each microservice.

Now, I am learning NestJs and its microservice approach. I've noticed that nestjs uses TCP as the default transport layer which is different from the way it is done with Spring Boot.

Why does nestjs prefer those transport layers (TCP, AMPQ) instead of HTTP? isn't HTTP the transport protocol for rest microservices?

From NestJs documentation:

> "a microservice is fundamentally an application that uses a different **transport** layer than HTTP"

Comment: HTTP uses TCP. It depends on your point of view. If you look at it from the OSI model, HTTP is **not** a transport layer. HTTP is an application layer. Transport layer is not supposed to have the concept of requests and responses. Transport layers only provide you byte, byte, byte, byte ... It is up to application layers like HTTP or FTP or SSH to give meaning to the bytes

Comment: Thanks for your comment @slebetman. From a networking point of view it is clear the relationship between HTTP and TCP but, from a microservice point of view, I still don't have clear why Nest prefers TCP over HTTP for microservices communication, indeed, you loose the HTTP Methods from a Rest API design.

Comment: @DanielStefanelli, Did find answer to your point? I am also interested in the design decision. Thank!

Comment: @DanielStefanelli why would you create microservices with HTTP as transport layer? For this, you can simply create 2 NestJs Apps and it will be the same thing.

Answer (score 7):

The main reason is it is slow. The problem with HTTP approach is that, with HTTP, JSON can generate an unwanted processing time to send and translate the information.

One problem with http-json is the serialization time of JSON sent. This is an expensive process and imagine serialization for a big data.

In addition to JSON, there are a number of HTTP headers that should be
interpreted further which may be discarded. The only concern should be to maintain a single layer for sending and receiving messages. Therefore, the HTTP protocol with JSON to communicate
between microservices is very slow. There are some optimization techniques and those are complex and does not add significant performance benefits

Also,HTTP spends more time waiting than it does transfer data.

Answer (score 6):

If you look a the OSI model, HTTP is part of Layer 7 (Application). TCP is Layer 4 (Transport).

When looking at Layer 4 there is no determining characteristic that makes it HTTP, AMPQ, gRPC, or RTSP. Layer 4 is explicitly how data is transmitted and received with the remote device.

---

Now, this is where networking and the software development worlds collide. Networking people will use "transport" meaning Layer 4, while Programming people use "transport" meaning the way a packet of data is transmitted to another component.

The meaning of "transport" (or "transporter" as used in the docs) is used as an abstraction from how messages are shared in this architecture.

Looking at the documentation if you are looking for something like AMPQ for your microservice you can use [NATS](https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/nats) or [REDIS](https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/redis) (both implementations are built by them).

https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/basics#getting-started

[image: OSI Layer]